# Kendo grid destroy button exceeding from the grid

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo grid on my ASP.NET MVC application.And there is a destroy command button on the grid.But when resize the screen the kendo grid Delete button(destroy command button) exceeding from the grid.

Below is the screen shot of the grid :-

[image]

Below is the piece of code for grid command button :-

```
columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Title("Delete");
.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(false))
```

I tried changes with its css but nothing is working.How can we fix it according to screen size ?

Comment: Can you please provide the full code so we can look at it? And by resizing are you referring to make the screen smaller?? Thanks.

Comment: are you referencing any other .css or .js files to the page other than Kendo?

Comment: yes i am doing the screen size smaller.